# Firestore Transactions is not handling race condition

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

## Objective

User on click a purchase button on the web frontend, it will send a POST request to the backend to create a purchase order. First, it will check the number of `available` stocks. If `available` is greater than 0, reduce `available` by 1 and then create the order.

## The setup

Backend (NestJS) queries the Firestore for the latest `available` value, and reduce `available` by 1. For debugging, I will return the `available` value.

```js
  let available;
  try {
    await runTransaction(firestore, async (transaction) => {
      const sfDocRef = doc(collection(firestore, 'items_available'), documentId);
      const sfDoc = await transaction.get(sfDocRef);
      if (!sfDoc.exists()) {
        throw 'Document does not exist!';
      }
      const data = sfDoc.data();
      available = data.available;
      if(available>0){
        transaction.update(sfDocRef, {
          available: available-1,
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Transaction failed: ', e);
  }
  return { available };
```

## My stress test setup

Our goal is to see all API requests having different `available` value, this would mean that Firestore Transactions is reducing the value even though there are multiple requests coming in.

I wrote a simple multi-threaded program that queries the backend's create order API, it will query the `available` value and return the `available` value. This program will save the `available` value returned for each API request.

The stress test performed is about 10 transactions per second, as I have 10 concurrent processes querying the backend. Each process will `http.get` 20 queries:

```js
const http = require('http');

function call(){
  http.get('http://localhost:5000/get_item_available', res => {
    let data = [];
    res.on('data', chunk => {
      data.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Response: ', Buffer.concat(data).toString());
    });
  }).on('error', err => {
    console.log('Error: ', err.message);
  });
}
for (var i=0; i<20; i++){
  call();
}
```

## The problem

Unfortunately, the `available` values I got from the requests contains repeated values, that is, having same `available` values instead of having unique `available` values.

What is wrong? Isn't Firestore Transactions meant to handle race conditions? Any suggestions on what I could change to handle multiple requests hitting the server and return a new value for each request?

Answer (score 3):

You have a `catch` clause to handle when the transaction fails, but then still end up returning a value to the caller `return { available }`. In that situation you should return an error to the caller.

Comment: Hi Frank. Thank you! You are right about that. I moved the return available into the `try` block, and now I'm getting many `{"code":"failed-precondition","name":"FirebaseError"}`. Looks like my design for this requirement (to get available at each call) is flawed.

Comment: If the real use-case is to decrement, consider using the [atomic increment/decrement operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value), which has much better throughput and no contention.